# How to download a PDF file from Dash

Tags: python, download, plotly-dash

I want the user to be able to download a PDF file. But when I click on the link, it downloads an empty file, and when opening the file it shows an error message (failed to load the document).

The file is already saved in the assets folder.

This is the part of the code I'm using:

```
html.Div(html.A('Download file', download='metodologia.pdf', href='./assets/metodologia.pdf')
```

Comment: Have you tried `href=app.get_asset_url('metodologia.pdf')` instead of `href='./assets/metodologia.pdf'`?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked this way.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the `Download` component from `dash-extensions==0.0.41`. Here is a small example from [the docs](https://github.com/thedirtyfew/dash-extensions#download),

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html  
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input
from dash_extensions import Download
from dash_extensions.snippets import send_file

app = dash.Dash(prevent_initial_callbacks=True)
app.layout = html.Div([html.Button("Download", id="btn"), Download(id="download")])

@app.callback(Output("download", "data"), [Input("btn", "n_clicks")])
def func(n_clicks):
    return send_file("/home/emher/Documents/Untitled.png")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

As compared to your current solution, this approach has a few advantages. Since a blob is used under the hood, larger files are supported. Furthermore, you are not limited to downloading files from the `assets` folder.